# PHP - Use function for one key in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, timestamp

I'm creating one simple blog script and I have this problem:

In MySQL I'm saving `PostDate` as `TIMESTAMP`, and when I select from MYSQL `PostDate` looks like this `2015-10-25 13:53:35`, but I want to convert this timestamp to `H:M D-M-Y`. I'm created one function for converting but I don't know how to use it for key `PostDate` in array. Exactly I want to rewrite all `PostData` keys in array to new format. I know how to do it with `foreach` loop but I cant do this because I use Smarty Template Engine.

ConvertTimestamp():

```
public function ConvertTimestamp($Timestamp)
{
  $TimeDate = explode(' ', $Timestamp);
  $Date = explode('-', $TimeDate['0']);
  $Date = $Date[2].'-'.$Date['1'].'-'.$Date['0'];
  $Time = explode(':', $TimeDate['1']);
  $Time = $Time['0'].':'.$Time['1'];
  $TimeDate = $Time.' '.$Date;
  return $TimeDate;
}
```

Comment: An incredibly complicated piece of string manipulation: Why don't you simply use PHP's built-in date or DateTime object functions, and you could make it a simple two lines of code, and even make it easier to change your mind over what format you might want to use in the future

Comment: `public function ConvertTimestamp($dateTimeValue, $format='H:i d-M-Y')
{
  $dto = new DateTime($dateTimeValue);
  return $dto->format($format);
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this simple code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this format `2015-10-25 13:53:35` is called **datetime** format not **TIMESTAMP** .

But anyway , to convert datetime to any format you want you can do this at mysql side . Suppose the table you select the data from is called "**test_table**" and has a datetime field called **PostDate** in that table which you want to convert to this format `H:M D-M-Y` ( which is what you want ) , you can do the following query :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(PostDate,'%H:%M %D-%M-%Y') FROM `test_table`
```